# Facebook login dialog error sdk 5

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I am having problem with Facebook login. When I open app for the first time, it does not show me native dialog to accept the permissions and gets error- (com.facebook.sdk error 5.). When I run app again, it shows me normally the dialog and works normally. When I tried to add alert in there, it has none effect and doesn`t show anything.

```
  NSArray *permissions = @[@"email"];
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        // Was login successful ?
        if (!user) {
            NSString *errorMessage = nil;

            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                errorMessage = @"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.";

                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];


            }
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error"
                                                            message:errorMessage
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];

        } else {
            if (user.isNew) {
                NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {

                        if ([user objectForKey:@"email"]) {

                            NSString *deviceName = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
                            PFUser *usere = [PFUser currentUser];
                            [usere setObject:[user objectForKey:@"first_name"] forKey:@"name"];
                            [usere setObject:[user objectForKey:@"last_name"] forKey:@"surname"];
                            [usere setObject:[user objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"mail"];
                            [usere setObject:[user objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"username"];
                            [usere setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"col2"];
                            [usere setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"col1"];
                            [usere setObject:deviceName forKey:@"phoneId"];

                            [usere saveEventually];
                            NSLog(@"SASO:%@",user);
                            [self boolea];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSString *deviceName = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
                            PFUser *usere = [PFUser currentUser];
                            [usere setObject:[user objectForKey:@"first_name"] forKey:@"name"];
                            [usere setObject:[user objectForKey:@"last_name"] forKey:@"surname"];
                            [usere setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"col2"];
                            [usere setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"col1"];
                            [usere setObject:deviceName forKey:@"phoneId"];

                            [usere saveEventually];
                            NSLog(@"SASO:%@",user);
                            [self bez];
                        }




                    }
                }];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
                [self boolea];

            }

        }


    }];

}
```